# Enable Windows 10 Sandbox on an old CPU (one that doesn't support SLAT)

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I know that you can't enable windows 10 sandbox on a CPU that doesn't support SLAT.

My actual question is that is there a way to bypass it? either by virtual box or any other VM's.

Like if you could start an unsavable windows 10 in a VM, that resets every time you restart the VM.

The main reason I'm doing this is to run risky programs.

Comment: Please don't write your whole question in bold text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My actual question is that is there a way to bypass it?

Windows Sandbox requires SLAT support due to the fact Microsoft Hyper-V requires it.  If your processor does not support SLAT then it does not meet the requirements to run Windows Sandbox.  **What you want is currently not possible with the current version of Windows Sandbox.**

> either by virtual box or any other VM's.

At this time Windows Sandbox only support Microsoft Hyper-V

> The main reason I'm doing this is to run risky programs.

You might want to do some research on this subject.  I have seen videos, authored by an individual who tests security software (reviews the effectiveness), Windows Sandbox (which was running within a Virtual Machine) was able to infected the host OS.

Comment: Thanks, by risky programs I meant not that risky (like to see a python virus I programmed)

Answer (score 0):

Run Linux and then run it in a Linux virtual machine running windows.
So been around in development 8 years ago // 15 years ago // 30 years ago; when this was all discussed heatedly.. back to conception through adding vt-d, about 8 years or so ago mainstream on HW. VTd- enables memory registers for the processor on any OS to SHIFT the hardware addresses and re-associate them. Under the current situation, this is how it should be done.. its safer and faster. It is also not the only method to achieve this. When vt-d came out I saw a feature being added that Amazon AWS adopted immediately and that allowed their virtual system to give the users the capability to put virtual machines inside of their virtual machines; thats what VT-d or SLATE helps do. The main feature reason why its "required" is a marketing and feature hungry big company reason. That being said of course Microsoft is going to be the first ones to adopt this method off the bat it forces people individuals not other companies into purchasing newer non Legacy HW.   All that being said we as individuals are not amazon aws and not all of us require virtual machines to have little virtual machines inside of them i personally believe that this feature should be optional, but as windows goes it just wants the feature with minimal coding required to implement it as an option; So we all no longer have compatibility with Legacy HW because of this So my suggestion use Linux :)  CHEERS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).